# How to hide one option of associated field in Simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

**price_plan.rb** - this model have boolean attribute :hidden

```
has_many :users
```

**user.rb**

```
belongs_to :price_plan
```

in user edit form:

```
<%= f.association :price_plan, as: :radio_buttons, required: true, label: 'Select plan', hidden: ?????????? %>
```

How can I make it?  I tried this way: `hidden: lambda{ |price_plan| price_plan.hidden }` It doesn't work.

Comment: it would be helpful to see the errors returned, but, and i'm totally guessing, is it related to referencing price_plan instead of f.price_plan?

Comment: if the value is false, do you really want it to be a hidden field, or do you want the field to not even be part of the form at all?

Comment: we talk about to hide one or more radiobuttons from group. but I think I'll do it with scope.

Comment: I tried to do `scope :public_plan,-> { where(hidden: false) }` and in the form `f.association :price_plan.public_plan` but it's an error `undefined method 'public_plan' for :price_plan:Symbol`

Comment: i believe the code above will create a method PricePlan.public_plan, which will return all public plans. you seem to be trying to call a class method on a symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I wasn't clear with my question. Here is what I needed:

**price_plan.rb**

```
scope :public_plan,-> { where(hidden: false) }
```

in the form:

```
<%= f.association :price_plan, :collection => PricePlan.public_plan, as: :radio_buttons, required: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<%= f.association :price_plan, as: :radio_buttons, required: true, label: 'Select plan', disabled: lambda{ |price_plan| price_plan.hidden? } %>
```

For hiding you can try the following code. Hope it works.

```
<% display_none = 'display:none' %>
<% display_block = 'display:block' %>
<%= f.association :price_plan, as: :radio_buttons, required: true, label: 'Select plan', style: "#{ lambda{ |price_plan| price_plan.hidden? } ? display_none : display_block }" %>
```

Comment: This will work for disabling the options, but I don't need to disable the options, my target is to hide them!

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'display_none'` with last update

Comment: a savvy user could still find the element and change it though, correct? if you used a hidden field would that still be the case?

Answer (score 0):

still not sure if i understand the exact goal, but is this closer to what you're looking for?

```
<% if f.price_plan %>
   <%= f.association :price_plan, as: :radio_buttons, required: true, label: 'Select plan' %>
<% else %>
   <% f.hidden_field :price_plan %>
<% end %>
```